# Conversion of Python code plot into Dash and Plotly plot

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, plotly

I have this code:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(14, 8))

for xcol, ax in zip(dff.columns.values, axes):
    dff.plot(kind='scatter', x=xcol, y=selected_dropdown_value, ax=ax, alpha=0.5, 
    color='r')
```

I need to convert it into something that Plotly and Dash can work with as in this example: https://plot.ly/pandas/line-and-scatter/. How can I do that? A dataframe is created out of values that users selects on the dropdown and then all columns are plotted against col_to_plot.. columns.

UPDATE:
Data is the following:

```
country   year  type color col_to_plot_1   col_to_plot_2  ... 

France   1991   t1    blue      200              3.5
Belgium  1992   t2    black      30              100.5
...      ...    ..     ...       ...               ...
```

Comment: pretty hard to tell without seeing what your data looks like.

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: Does anyone know?